# Safe-app doesn't wait for transaction execution

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I created a custom safe-app using safe-apps-react-sdk. The Dapp shows the transaction results as soon as the transaction enters processing stage and doesn't wait for its execution. In multisig transactions, the results are displayed just after signing of transaction by the first owner and it doesn't wait for confirmations from other owners.
I am using the following code to send the transaction to safe.

```
async function submitTx (tx) {
    try {
      const safeTx = await sdk.txs.send({
        txs: [tx],
      })
      console.log("Safe tx: ", { safeTx })
      return safeTx.txStatus
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
```

Here is the usage of the above function:

```
try {
        await submitTx(tx);
        var wallets = await walletCreator.returnUserWallets(address);
        console.log(wallets);
        var wallet = wallets[wallets.length - 1];
        var contract = new ethers.Contract(wallet, SharedWallet.abi, provider);
        setCurrWallet(contract);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```